# SpriteKit Frame Rate Drop

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, frame-rate

In my SpriteKit game, I've been noticing that the game looks fairly jittery in places, but the frame rate never drops below 55 or so. Is this jittery-ness an artifact of the frame rate drop or could there be something else going on? What is the best way to find out what is causing the issue?

Comment: Have you ran your code using Instruments?

Comment: I have tried, but it often crashes in the AppDelagate for some reason. Do you know of any good tutorials on how to use instruments to understand what it's telling me?

Comment: You should provide a lot more context about the issue. If you are not familliar with instruments, you can try to remove part after part of your app in order to locate which part of an app is responsible for jittering... Also, maybe you are doing something silly like moving objects at the same time by physics and by actions. Something like that might produce jittering at 60 fps :)

Comment: I apologize for not being more specific - it doesn't give you a lot to work with. In my didBeginContact method, I'm checking for physics bodies colliding, and in my update method I'm looping through small arrays that hold information to react to other things that aren't physics related. I've tried commenting these out but the problem persists. I think it must be a graphics issue. I've noticed my draw count can get up to 40-50 even with less than 100 nodes on the screen, so that's what I'm investigating currently. Thank you for your previous comments!

Comment: Did you test on a physical device? Which one(s)? Note that performance in the simulator is not representative of real-world performance - for Sprite Kit, devices typically perform better than the Simulator.

Comment: Yes, I tested it on an iPhone 6.